# How to kill or cancel an asynchronous call in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm sending the following request to an MVC controller:

```
var datum = { param1: value, param2: value, param3: value };

$.ajax
({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: getAbsolutePath() + "Controller/MethodName",
  dataType: "json",
  data: JSON.stringify(datum),
  success: function (response) 
  {
    var result = response;
  }
});
```

Sometimes response takes too much time. I'm looking for a way to kill or cancel this request. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's the point of cancelling the request? Just have your "success" handler ignore the response if it's too much delayed.

Comment: response takes to much time and my page got stuck. untill response comes.

Comment: If you're page is stuck then you're not making an **asynchronous** call.  That code you posted would definitely be asynchronous, so the only way your page would be "stuck" would be through some other mechanism of your own, and you have not posted or described that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.abort()` to cancel the request:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: getAbsolutePath() + "Controller/MethodName",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(datum),
    success: function (response) {
        var result = response;
    }
});

xhr.abort();
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 3):

jquery .ajax returns normalized XMLHttpRequest, just use its abort method:

```
var xhr = $.ajax(params);
xhr.abort();
```

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion, use the timeout property:

```
$.ajax
({
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   url: getAbsolutePath() + "Controller/MethodName",
   timeout: 100000,   //cancels automatically after 100 seconds
   dataType: "json",
   data: JSON.stringify(datum),
   success: function (response) 
   {
     var result = response;
   }
 });
```

Comment: Why did the ones who suggested using timeout receive a downvote? I think it's a useful suggestion to the problem.

Comment: I agree; it's a fine way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `timeout` property for `ajax` to cancel the request if it takes too much time

Refer http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/